# What's the problem with ng-content in web component?

Tags: angular, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a custom web component with this structure:

```
<div (click)="popup.showAsComponent()">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

I use it like this:

```
<my-web-component><button>Click!</button></my-web-component>
```

When I use it in my application, it doesn't work correctly everywhere. In one of the modules, it works correctly and displayed in html inspector like so:

```
#shadow-root [
 <style>...</style>
 <link href="..."></link>
 <div>
  <button>Click!</button>
 <div> 
]
```

and in the another (main) module, the content that I add to this component goes beyond the shadow-root:

```
#shadow-root [
 <style>...</style>
 <link href="..."></link>
 <div>
 <div> 
]
<button>Click!</button>
```

What do you think might be the problem? Because I have no options

*Edited 1*:
And if I wrap the component in which this error occurs in a separate module, the error still remains.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that you need to use your custom element into an Angualr 2+ component.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).